# Получить список названий приложений на android

Tags: android, shell, adb

Есть ли возможность через adb получить список названий приложений (не пакетов, а именно названий)?
Один из способов найти apk и через aapt посмотреть в манифесте название. 
Есть ли другие способы (т.к. пробегать apk всех приложений на устройстве, по-моему, неправильно)?

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать **adb shell dumpsys package** что-то получить и очень похожие на имена названия вы увидите в полях codePath и других

> Package [com.example.android.softkeyboard] (4173b238):
>
> ```
> userId=10043 gids=[]
>
> pkg=Package{41822218 com.example.android.softkeyboard}
>
> codePath=/data/app/SoftKeyboard.apk
>
> resourcePath=/data/app/SoftKeyboard.apk
>
> nativeLibraryPath=/data/app-lib/SoftKeyboard
>
> versionCode=18 targetSdk=18
> ```

Comment: К сожалению это не то, уже пробовал вытаскивать dump и там ничего подходящего нет. Только название пакета,а оно не всегда соответствует названию приложения, даже если добавить пробелы)

Answer (score 0):

Как вам такое

```
private List<String> setup() {
    List<String> appNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Intent startUpIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startUpIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(startUpIntent, 0);

    for (ResolveInfo s : activities) {
        appNames.add(s.loadLabel(pm).toString());
    }
    return appNames;
}
```